# Why isn't my table 100% wide?

Tags: html, html-table, width

On a 100% wide page, I want a table that fills the whole screen.  I'm having problems with the first table with image.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" align="center">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="$bordercolor">
<table border="0" cellspacing="100%" cellpadding="$tablespace" width="100%" >
<tr>
<td class="tablerow" bgcolor="$altbg2" background="images/idown/bga.png">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
<tr>
<td class="tablerow" align="left">$lang[loggedin] <a href=member.php?action=viewpro&amp;member=$xmbuser>$xmbuser</a> $loginout | $lastvisittext <br>$newu2umsg</td>
<td class="tablerow" align="right" >$searchlink $links $pluglink</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

(Also http://ydown.totalh.com/forum/.)

Comment: `<table style="width: 100%;">` will work just fine. Is this what you need?

Answer (score 2):

You have nested tables. If you really want to have 100% on that table, you need to add your width 100% to both the outer and inner table. The outer table has a width set to 1028px.

Answer (score 1):

Because we can't see your HTML (only generated HTML) there's no way to debug your problem.  According to the rendered HTML, you have a width set to 1028px.

Tables aren't a good fit at all for page layout.  You should be attacking this particular problem with CSS -- Divs specifically.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the table that is the parent of the one you posted code for.

```
<table width="1028px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
```

Its width is set to 1028px, not 100%.  Set it instead to 100%.

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#cacaca" align="center">
```

Comment: @langel - Change all instances of width="1028 px" or width="1028px" to width="100%".  If you're still having problems, update the code in your original question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question probably has nothing to do with nested tables for most people.  There is actually some border or margin present in the body element containing the table.  You should add some style attributes like `margin:0px;border:0px` to the `BODY` element to eliminate it.